# Illegal State exception mongo-hadoop and spark

Tags: java, mongodb, exception, apache-spark

I get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: not ready" in org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder._decode while trying to use MongoDB as input RDD:

Just like: [Exception while connecting to mongodb in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226515/exception-while-connecting-to-mongodb-in-spark)

The tasks completes fully with what seems to be the correct results however I get the following without fail on each run.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: not ready
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder._decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:139)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.input.MongoInputSplit.readFields(MongoInputSplit.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable.readObject(ObjectWritable.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable.readFields(ObjectWritable.java:77)
    at org.apache.spark.SerializableWritable.readObject(SerializableWritable.scala:42)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.readExternal(ShuffleMapTask.scala:140)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1837)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

AND

```
Loss was due to org.bson.BSONException
org.bson.BSONException: should be impossible
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:126)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.input.MongoInputSplit.readFields(MongoInputSplit.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable.readObject(ObjectWritable.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable.readFields(ObjectWritable.java:77)
    at org.apache.spark.SerializableWritable.readObject(SerializableWritable.scala:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.readExternal(ShuffleMapTask.scala:140)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1837)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Would love any input. Theres try catches in every spark function block with default return values so I'm certain that I'm not causing any exceptions to propagate upwards.

The only places I can think of this happening would be in

```
file_save.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("file:///bogus", Object.class, Object.class, MongoOutputFormat.class, config);
```

AND

```
JavaPairRDD<Object, BSONObject> mongoRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(config, com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat.class, Object.class, BSONObject.class);
```

I would be happy to provide more info.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm facing the same problem.  It occurs when I try to use (e.g. count) a specific RDD.